# Unable to compile the nn library - is gcc not installed?

Tags: windows, gcc, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to make a neuronal network project using [nn](https://crates.io/crates/nn) and I think I am using it correctly.

My problem started when I tried to compile with `cargo`. I don't know if this is a Windows problem or what, but my friend can compile perfectly with the same OS. Here's the error I get on both of my computers:

```
C:\Users\juanr_000\Desktop\red_neuronal>cargo run

Compiling time v0.1.24 
failed to run custom build command for `time v0.1.24`

Process didn't exit successfully: C:\Users\juanr_000\Desktop\red_neuronal\target\debug\build\time-72cc226455b1c02b\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)

--- stdout
TARGET = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR = Some("C:\\Users\\juanr_000\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1285ae84e5963aae\\time-0.1.24")

OUT_DIR = Some("C:\\Users\\juanr_000\\Desktop\\red_neuronal\\target\\debug\\build\\time-72cc226455b1c02b\\out")

TARGET = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
PROFILE = Some("debug")
debug 0
TARGET = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

HOST = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

CC_i686-pc-windows-gnu = None

CC_i686_pc_windows_gnu = None

HOST_CC = None

CC = None

TARGET = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

HOST = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

CFLAGS_i686-pc-windows-gnu = None

CFLAGS_i686_pc_windows_gnu = None

HOST_CFLAGS = None

CFLAGS = None

TARGET = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

HOST = Some("i686-pc-windows-gnu")

CC_i686-pc-windows-gnu = None

CC_i686_pc_windows_gnu = None

HOST_CC = None

CC = None

running: "gcc" "-O0" "-c" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-mwin32" "-m32" "C:\Users\juanr_000\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1285ae84e5963aae\time0.1.24\src/time_helpers.c" "-o" "C:\Users\juanr_000\Desktop\red_neuronal\target\debug\build\time-72cc226455b1c02b\out\src\time_helpers.o" 

failed to execute command: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
.
(os error 2)
is `gcc` not installed?

--- stderr
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\juanr_000\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1285ae84e5963aae\gcc-0.3.4\src\lib.rs:380
```

I changed the `Cargo.toml`, and I think other packages downloaded and installed correctly. It could be a gcc problem, but I have an up-to-date mingw installed and in my path.

Sorry for that pasted "code", Stack Overflow does not allow me to post images yet. Sorry for my English too!

Comment: Do you have gcc on the path? It asks "is `gcc` not installed?"

Comment: *Stack Overflow does not allow me to post images yet* — that's a good thing; you **shouldn't** post images of text! Text is searchable and far easier to read! However, you may want to double check the output. It looks like some lines are duplicates. Perhaps something went wrong when copying?

Comment: No, it is not duplicate I think, look at the output here: http://es.tinypic.com/r/2r5t3dg/8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crate you are trying to compile (`time`, a dependency of `nn`) includes a custom build script to compile non-Rust code. This requires GCC, which appears to be unavailable, and compilation fails. Crates that consist of Rust code only will compile fine.

The binaries installed by MinGW sometimes have different names than `gcc`, so even if they are installed and in your `PATH`, there might not be a binary called `gcc`. I am using `gcc` from the [MinGW-builds project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/), which does provide a `gcc` executable.

Comment: It is called "gcc" on "C:\MinGW\bin", so I'm not sure where is the problem. I have been programming on C for a while and It works, so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: If you run `where gcc` in a `cmd` prompt, does it print `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`?

Comment: The problem was gcc at the end and I installed win-build to this. Thank you!